# How to define specific option for database values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have model `User`.

I want to `@user` to be 3 types : `admin`, `regular` and `pro`.

If I create column `type:String`, of course I can pass string, when creating new `@user`, 'admin'/'regular'/'pro'.

And then each time I operate with `@user` check something like

```
if @user.type == 'admin'
```

for my purposes.

But I feel that this is not how it is made by professional developers. (Am I right here?)

I want `User` model to have column which can only contain 3 specific values and not just any string.

Comment: I think you should take consider using self joins for this. Check 2.10 Self join in the rails guide. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

The column should be in integer,with a default value (probably 0 in the following example). And in your model define it as:

```
enum type: { regular: 0, pro: 1, admin: 2 }
```

for example.

Now you automatically have these methods:

```
@user.regular?
@user.pro?
@user.admin?
```

Also, you can call @user.type and you will get a nice string representation:

```
> @user.type
=> "admin"
```

You can also query with a symbol like:

```
User.where(type: [:pro, :regular])
```

or

```
User.where.not(type: :admin)
```

etc.

This approach also works perfectly well with the CanCan gem.

Comment: This works very well indeed. It should be the answer actually

Comment: It's not my question ;)

Comment: Oops. Sorry @RichPeck :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign roles in your application , you can simply use the `Role-Based` specific gems like `Cancan` and `Rollify` etc. The link to which is [here](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial). I will explain below how easy it would be to assign roles to users and yes how the professional developers do it.

In your `User` model , there will be a method as :

```
ROLES = %w[admin regular pro]

def role?(base_role)
  ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
end
```

Now in your `UsersController` you can check whether :

```
if user.role? :admin
  can :manage, Post
end
if user.role? :regular
  can :manage, ForumThread
end
if user.role? :pro
  can :manage, Forum
end
```

It's that easy ..!!!. 
I hope this helped ..!!! :)